# Interfacing 16C554 UART to ARM based CPU

Tags: serial, uart, rs232

Due to deficit of UART's on my board (LPC3141 based) I have the idea to add external multi-channel UART.
It has data and address lines, which I'm pretty sure needs to be connected to EBI. Unfortunately surfing the web for several hours didn't made me happy.

Any links, hints or other info will be highly appreciated :-)

Parts to be used:

- [LPC3141](http://ics.nxp.com/products/lpc3000/lpc313x.lpc314x.lpc315x/~LPC3141/) ARM CPU
- [SC16C554](http://www.nxp.com/pip/SC16C554_554D.html) Quad UART

Comment: If you can link us to the different parts you are using you will normally get a much improved set of answers.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem and also chose an NXP UART. I picked the [SC16IS740](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SC16IS740_750_760.pdf). It only supports a single channel, but rather than connecting to an external address and data bus it is driven with I2C or SPI.

There's also an interrupt line to alert of incoming data.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for SPI-to-UART. The question is not about picking the alternative, but rather about how to interconnect these two parts :-)